# Выпадающий список с подпунктами

Tags: jquery, html, html5, javascript, css

Добрый день, уважаемые специалисты. Хочу узнать, кто из Вас и как делает выпадающие списки с подпунктами.

Задачу ставлю следующим образом:
Необходимо сделать выпадающий список с подпунктами, т.е.:

```
Пункт 0;  
Пункт 1;  
__Подпункт 1;  
__Подпункт 2;  
Пункт 3;
```

И так далее.

Отличительная особенность задачи: пункты и подпункты - это не текст и не ссылки, а элементы выбора:

```
<select name="_">
          <option value="__">АААА</option>
          <option value="__">ББББ</option>
</select>
```

То есть при помощи этого меню возможно в рамках страницы выбрать элемент, который может передать некое значение в форму для последующей обработки сервером.

У меня есть свой вариант решения данной задачи при помощи javascript, но мне кажется он очень корявым, поэтому интересно, как решили бы эту задачу другие пользователи.

Comment: [optgroup][1]?

   [1]:http://htmlbook.ru/html/optgroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> чтобы при наведении на пункты меню выезжали подпункты.

Можно использовать любое выпадающее многоуровневое меню. В пункты/подпункты добавить атрибут **data-*** с необходимыми значениями и при клике на них брать это значение и записывать в скрытый input ( *type=hidden* ). [Смотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/q0rj1a0n/). Там я не стал играться со стилями и добавлять прочие плюшки, и input сделал не скрытым для наглядности.

Comment: О, хороший вариант. Принято!

Answer (score 0):

Для этих целей использую **select2.js**

Подробная информация [тут](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-latest.html)

Comment: Хорошо, но нет. Задача этим не решается.
Необходимо что-то типа:
http://shpargalkablog.ru/2012/06/vypadayushcheye-menyu-css.html
Тоесть, что бы при наведении на пункты меню, выезжали подпункты.